# How can we calculate the mathematical expectation of a Dirac delta?

Tags: probability, lebesgue-integral, dirac-delta

The expected value of a function $g$ of a random variable $X$ is defined as the Stieljes integral:

$$E[g(x)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \,dF(x),$$

where $F(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X$. In practice, we also have:

$$E[g(x)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) f(x) \,dx,$$

where $f(x)$ is the density function. I am working with the function $g(x) = a \, \text{sech}^2(a \, x)$. From an engineer's point of view, this function resembles a Dirac delta (multiplied by 2) for large enough $a$. Consequently, I tried to calculate $E[\delta(x)]$ rather than $E[a \, \text{sech}^2(a \, x)]$ for very large $a$. On the one hand, I got:

$$E[\delta(x)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) f(x)\, dx = f(0).$$

On the other hand, using the first formula,

$$E[\delta(x)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)\, dF(x).$$

Since $\delta$ is equal to zero almost everywhere, the set $\{x:\delta(x) \neq 0\} = \{ 0 \}$ is countable and hence has a Lebesgue measure of zero. I have read that if the Lebesgue measure is zero, the integral is zero even if the value of the function is infinite. Hence, it follows that

$$E[\delta(x)] = 0.$$

Obviously, there is a flaw in my calculations. Actually I am familiar with Riemann integration and have little understanding of Lebesgue integration.

P.S.: Computer simulations give one result or the other depending on the ratio between $a$ and the sample size.

Comment: The Dirac delta-function, despite its name, cannot be realised as a Lebesgue-integrable function (as you have discovered).

Comment: The Dirac delta-function, despite its name, is not a function hence the object δ(x), where x denotes a random variable, simply does not exist.

Answer (score -2):

The dirac delta is what is called a *[generalised function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function)*.

Basically, the dirac delta is *defined* to work as a useful *exception* to the usual rule of a discrete atom having zero Lebesgue measure.

As an exception, naturally it doesn't follow the rule.   So, *if* it is *useful* to do so then we might *extend* the notion of expectation to say:

$$\mathsf E(\delta(X-c)) = f(c)$$

Comment: And then we would need to face the inconvenient truth that one can decide that $f(c)=42$ or that $f(c)=0$ or... and still have valid PDFs $f$.